# Conver scientific format timestamp to date excel

Tags: excel

I have difficulty in converting the timestamp recorded in excel. The format is in scientific, I would like to convert to date format in excel.

Scientific = 2.02207E+13 (in number format 20220715030838)

I expect the result will be 15-Jul-2022 03:08

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula to convert date/time value.

```
=--TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,MID(A1&"",{1,5,7},{4,2,2}))+(--TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,MID(A1&"",{9,11,13},{2,2,2})))
```

Then use cell format to display results as desired format. Or can use `TEXT()` function like-

```
=TEXT(--TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,MID(A1&"",{1,5,7},{4,2,2}))+(--TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,MID(A1&"",{9,11,13},{2,2,2}))),"dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm")
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Than you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ans]

My answer is here, make sure that singe digit date should come with **0** as highlighted in the pic. Either you can customise the format or use Text function.
If you want seconds as well then use Right(A2,2) function in **Second** argument in the Time function. Hope it clears.

=TEXT(INT(DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),MID(A2,7,2)))+TIME(MID(A2,9,2),MID(A2,11,2),),"dd-mmm-yyy hh:mm")

=INT(DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),MID(A2,7,2)))+TIME(MID(A2,9,2),MID(A2,11,2),) #customise the format.